# how to increase Flutter launch_background.xml Splash Screen display time?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, splash-screen, flutter-animation

I've trying to run my app in debug mode, but my app was laggy and didn't get 60fps.
Then i'm trying to run my app in release mode with

```
flutter run --release
```

And i got 60 fps, but i got my image in **launch_background.xml** as Splash Screen disappearing too fast.
How to increase the display time, maybe 3 until 5 seconds, like in debug mode ?

Do me a favor please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate the exact time, It depends on the hardware and platform the application is running on it.

Flutter takes some time to render and this time is different for different devices.

But you can put a delay just before the `runApp` function, if you need to show the splash screen longer than flutter rendering time. like this:

```
void main() async {//make your main function async
  //put delay here with await:
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

  runApp(MyApp());
  //total splash time = your delay + the time that Flutter needs to render
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is going to work delay the splash screen?

Comment: @OMiShah Yes, you can try it.

Comment: It Works, Thanks a lot sir, appreciate it !